# How to execute Perl qx function with variable

Tags: perl, variables, interpolation

How do I get Perl's `qx` function to execute with my `$opt` variable?

Before (works):

```
my @df_output = qx (df -k /tmp);
```

I want to use either `-k`, `-g`, or `-H`:

```
my @df_output = qx (df -$opt /tmp);
```

Comment: What happened when you tried this code?

Comment: `Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./tst.pl`. Also `df: -: No such file or directory`. Interesting, I still get working output, but with these messgs.

Comment: Those mean `$opt` isn't defined.

Comment: @Eevee- thanks. that was the problem.

Comment: [Don't parse `df` output, it's a stupid idea.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6350466#comment-7437792)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have should work, **but**: don't ever use `qx`.  It's ancient and dangerous; whatever you feed to it goes through the shell, so it's very easy to be vulnerable to shell injection or run into surprises if `/bin/sh` isn't quite what you expected.

Use the multi-arg form of `open()`, which bypasses the shell entirely.

```
open my $fh, '-|', 'df', "-$opt", '/tmp' or die "Can't open pipe: $!";
my @lines = <$fh>;  # or read in a loop, which is more likely what you want
close $fh or die "Can't close pipe: $!";
```

Comment: `system` returns the exit status, not the process's stdout.  But it supports a safe multi-argument form too, yes.

Comment: Noone got around to implementing multi-arg open -| in Windows, though :(

Answer (score 3):

try to use backslash `\$opt`, it works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @IanAuld. Why is this not an answer?