# Optimized way to print directory paths recursively without file comparison in perl

Tags: perl

I have a directory which contains multiple levels of sub dirs. I want to print path for each and every directory.
Currently, I am using

```
use File::Find; 

find( 
{ 
    wanted => \&findfiles, 
}, $maindirectory); 
  
sub findfiles 
{ 
      if (-d) {
     push @arrayofdirs,$File::Find::dir;
     }   
}
```

But each subdirectory contains thousands of files at each level. The above code takes lot of time to provide the result as it compares each file for directory. Is there a way to get subdirectories path without comparing files to save time or any other optimized method?

Edit: This issue got partially resolved but a new issue came up because of this solution. I have listed it here: [Multiple File search in varying level of directories in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63016580/multiple-file-search-in-varying-level-of-directories-in-perl?noredirect=1#comment111510313_63016580)

Comment: The POSIX (and libc) function readdir does not provide the file type for each directory entry and thus one need to do an explicit or implicit (as in `-d`) stat(2) on the name. Using the getdents(2) function this could be optimized, but is specific for Linux. See  [using Linux getdents syscall](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1148448).

Comment: If you are on a UNIX/Linux platform then you can try reading output of `find $maindirectory -type d` into your program (see `perldoc -f qx`). That would be faster because a compiled C program (`find`) will be doing all the hard work. Something like `@dirs = split /\0/, qx(find $maindirectory -type d -print0);` should work.

Comment: Also the sample code you gave saves the container directory of each directory to the array, not the directory itself. I think this is not intended. You should use `$File::Find::name` if you wish to save the directory name.

Comment: I'm curious, how many files/levels/directories are we talking about?  It runs for me in under half a second on a ~3Gb hierarchy with close to 5k subdirectories.  NOTE: you don't want `$File::Find::dir` there but rather `$File::Find::name`.

Comment: Here I am talking about 20 levels each having about a hundred thousand sub-directories. Each sub-directory may contain about 70 files.

Comment: One of the problems you likely have is that the more things a directory contains, the slower things get. https://serverfault.com/questions/147731/do-large-folder-sizes-slow-down-io-performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on a UNIX/Linux platform then you can try reading output of `find $maindirectory -type d` command into your program (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378747) for a safe way to do that.). This command prints the names of directories in `$maindirectory`. It is faster because a compiled C program ([`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)) does all the hard work. The following script should print all directory paths found.

Sample script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $maindirectory = '.';
open my $fh, '-|', 'find', $maindirectory, '-type', 'd' or die "Can't open pipe: $!";
while( my $dir = <$fh>) {
    print $dir;
}
close $fh or warn "can't close pipe: $!";
```

Note that there is no point in calling `find` through perl and then just printing its output without any processing. You can just as well run `find $maindirectory -type d` in shell itself.

Comment: Have you tested/benchmarked to verify that there is a non-negligible difference in run time by using `find`? If the majority of the Perl program's time is spent doing `stat` calls (which are handled by a compiled C library, and likely the same library used by `find`), then it's very possible that there will be little or no difference.

Comment: @Dave I did some basic testing using `time`. Script using the sample given in question (after some correction) gives `real    *0m1.623s* user    0m1.030s sys     0m0.590s`. while the script in my answer gives `real    *0m0.493s* user    0m0.300s sys     0m0.150s`. Both on a directory having  870 directories in it. I think my approach is a faster because it avoids the `wanted` function call for each directory entry.

Comment: OK, yes, I'd say that's a non-negligible difference.  Thanks!