# Multiple File search in varying level of directories in perl

Tags: file, perl

I have a directory structures as follows. I want to have only the first path, not the paths which are present after the first file in the report.
I also don't want to check further in that report after getting first file, thus want to save time.

structure for directory:

```
Report 1
A--B--C--D--E--abc.txt--->needed this 
A--B--C--D--E--F--abc.txt avoid this
Report 2
A--B--C--D--E--Q--R--abc.txt needed this, as it is single in its report.
Report 3
A--H--I--J--abc.txt --needed this
Report 4
A--B--C--D--M--abc.txt needed this
A--B--C--D--M--N--abc.txt avoid this
.
.
.
.
```

millions of such reports.

Directory A contains millions of reports. Each report contains multiple files and subdirectories. Each report have abc.txt in one of the path present
and same path  post abc.txt level ,may contain other subdirectories inside the path which also have have abc.txt.

Note:
Reports are of varying level of subdirectories

```
open my $fh, '-|', 'find', $maindirectory, '-type','d' or die "cant open pipes $! \n";
                while (<$fh>) {
                    my $dirpath = $_;
                    chomp $dirpath;
                    if(-d $dirpath) {
                        $filewithpath = File::Spec->catfile( $dirpath, "abc.txt" );
                        if (-e $filewithpath) {
                            push @patharray, $filewithpath;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The module File::Find comes with Perl and is the canonical way to find files.  You might also look at File::Find::Rule.

Comment: I don't understand how you are picking which files you want. How is Report 5 distinct from Report 1, for instance?

Comment: @briandfoy you are right, I have removed the report 5.

Comment: @AndyLester I have studied a little about Find:File:Rule, but was not able to get my requirements fulfil..Can you please show me how to do so?

Comment: This can be done in shell itself with
`for i in Report* ; do find "$i" -type f -name abc.txt | head -1; done`
This will print the paths of first file `abc.txt` which it finds in each of the `Report*` directories.


Are you required to use perl for further processing of these file paths? You can do that by piping the output of the above command to your perl script that processes these paths.

Comment: @ApurvaChoudhary No, I'm sorry, I don't have the time to do a File::Find::Rule tutorial. I suggest that you try writing some code that uses it, and then post a new question that tells specifically what trouble you're having.

Comment: Okay, how is Report 2 different than Report 1? Why do you skip the file in F but then select the one in G?

Comment: @pii_ke The main issue is to reduce number of `Report*` as I am checking in each report if file exists using `perl -e $filewithpath` I am already getting list of all the available directories path even those which I don't need. And I want to get reports which contain first file itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ApurvaChoudhary I think you want the `abc.txt` files which are nearest to the main directory for a common initial path.
That is, you want to avoid looking for
`A/B/C/../F/abc.txt` if `A/B/C/abc.txt`
has been found. Is this correct? If not, then please clarify the file selection criteria.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the `abc.txt` files
which are nearest to the
main directory for a common initial path.
That is, you want to avoid looking for
`A/B/C/../F/abc.txt` if `A/B/C/abc.txt`
has been found.

This criteria will select files `A/H/I/J/abc.txt`,
`A/B/C/D/M/abc.txt`, `A/B/C/D/E/abc.txt` for your
sample directory tree.
And *not* `A/B/C/D/E/Q/R/abc.txt`,
which you have marked as needed in your sample,
because the file `A/B/C/D/E/abc.txt` has already
been found above it in the directory hierarchy.

You can do this in perl using:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;
my $maindirectory = "A";
#replace with actual main directory name

File::Find::find(
    sub {
        if ( -d && -f "$_/abc.txt" ) {
            $File::Find::prune = 1;
            process_path_of_needed_file("$File::Find::name/abc.txt");
        }
    },
    $maindirectory
);
```

See https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html