# Adding an || regex to a bash ``ed one-liner in a perl script

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I am trying to add an || regex to a bash ``ed one-liner in a perl script, if that makes any sense.

```
my $result = `df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom|none'  | awk '{ print \$1 "\t" \$5 " used."}'`; 

# .Private maybe the same as /dev/sdb1 so I'm trying to remove it too 
# by trying to add || (m/\.Private/) to the above

print  "$result";
```

So I am removing lines from the output that start with Filesystem, tmpfs, cdrom or none, at present, but I would also like to and the "or lines containing .Private" to the one-liner, if possible...

I have the below also, but want to reproduce its results with the above code...

```
my @result2 =Shell::df ("-H"); 
shift @result2;   # get rid of "Filesystem..."
for( @result2 ){
next if ((/^tmpfs|tmpfs|cdrom|none/) || (m/\.Private/));
my @words2 = split('\s+', $_);
print $words2[0], "\t", $words2[4], " used\.\n";
}
```

Comment: [Don't parse `df` output, it's a stupid idea.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6350466#comment-7437792)

Comment: The guy is probably studying and practicing, there's nothing wrong with his question. I know this is 4 years old but it's worth saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the `\.Private` part to the current regexp:

```
grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom|none|\.Private'
```

On a side note, the pattern `^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom|none` might not actually do what you want, as only `Filesystem` is matched at the beginning of the line, the other parts will be matched if they appear anywhere in the input. To match them at the beginning, change it to:

```
'^Filesystem|^tmpfs|^cdrom|^none'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you get rid of the "awk" part entirely. Calling awk from inside perl is silly.

Instead, rely on capturing lines using list context, and then do your processing inside perl.

`my @lines = df -H;`

my @results = grep ... @lines; # perl 'grep' builtin

If you insist on using the unix grep, why not just add '|.Private' to your grep exclusion pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't do what you think it does. It matches strings that start with `Fileystem` or that contain the other words anywhere.

Try with this:

```
grep -vE '^(Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom|none)|\.Private'
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
my $result = `df -H | grep -vE '(^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom|none)|\.Private'  | awk '{ print \$1 "\t" \$5 " used."}'`;
```