# df output in tabular form using perl

Tags: perl

Given the following command and its output:

```
ssh -q $server 'df -hP /raj*

Size   Used  Avail Capacity  Mounted On
200G  154G   44G  79% /raj_day
200G  154G   44G  49% /raj1_day
200G  154G   44G  39% /raj2_day
```

I would like to convert into Tabular format so presentation should be good. Also, want to display Capacity in sorting order. Any tips for me in perl?

My Script as follows...

```
#############################################
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

# Use either -h or -k flag or leave it blank for default (-k)
# -h for human-readable size output
# -k for 1k-block output
$flag = "-h";
@df = `df $flag`;

print "Content-type: text/htmln\n";
print "<table border=2>\n";
print "<tr>\n";

print "<td><b>Filesystem</b></td>\n";

if ($flag eq "-h") {
    print "<td><b>Size</b></td>\n";
}
else {
    print "<td><b>1k-blocks</b></td>\n";
}

print "<td><b>Used</b></td>\n";
print "<td><b>Avail</b></td>\n";
print "<td><b>Capacity</b></td>\n";
print "<td><b>Mounted on</b></td>\n";
print "</tr>\n";

foreach $line (@df) {
    next if ($line =~ /Filesystem/);

    ($fsystem,$blocks,$used,$avail,$capacity,$mounted) = split(/s+/,$line);

    print "fsystem is $fsystem\n";
    print "blocks is $blocks\n";
    print "used is $used\n";
    print "avail is $avail\n";
    print "capacity is $capacity\n";
    print "mounted is $mounted\n";

($number,$sign) = split(/%/,$capacity);
if ($number < 60) {
    print "<tr bgcolor=green>\n";
}
elsif (($number >= 60) && ($number < 90)) {
    print "<tr bgcolor=yellow>\n";
}
else {
    print "<tr bgcolor=red>\n";
}
#
print "<td>$fsystem</td>\n";
print "<td>$blocks</td>\n";
print "<td>$used</td>\n";
print "<td>$avail</td>\n";
print "<td>$capacity</td>\n";
print "<td>$mounted</td>\n";
print "</tr>\n";
}

print "</table>\n";
```

**OUTPUT AS FOLLOWS**

> Content-type: text/htmln  
>   **Filesystem** **Size** **Used**
>   **Avail** **Capacity** **Mounted
>   on**  fsystem is /dev/ blocks is da3              95G
>   33G   58G  36% /
>
> used is avail is capacity is mounted is fsystem is tmpf blocks is
>   499M   88K  499M   1% /dev/ used is hm
>
> avail is capacity is mounted is fsystem is /dev/ blocks is da1
>   124M   39M   79M  33% /boot
>
> used is avail is capacity is mounted is

Comment: Tip: [Don't parse `df` output, it's a stupid idea.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350466/regex-help-on-unix-df#comment-7437792)

Comment: @jack - oh. just now did it. Just new to this place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like daxim already pointed out: It's a stupid idea to parse the output of `df`, but if I had to hack down a small script it would probably look like this:

`df -B M -P /path1 /path2 /path3 | sed -e '1d' | sort -k 4,4 -r -h  | column -t`