# How do I replace G with white space?

Tags: regex, perl

I have to check the free space on a disk volume and am using the command `df -h`, which produces this output:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0               27G   24G  2.1G  92% /
udev                  506M  112K  506M   1% /dev
/dev/sda1             102M   40M   63M  39% /boot
```

This piece of script

```
my (@space, @freesp);
@space = grep /\/dev\/md0/,`df -h`;
print "@space\n";
```

is giving me

```
/dev/md0               27G   24G  2.1G  92% /
```

Which I can split on whitespace giving the values in `$freesp[0]`, `$freesp[1]` etc.

But I want to remove or replace that `G` with white space, so that I can compare `$freesp[3]` with some value and can proceed with my script.

So what is the regex I have to use for this to happen, or is there any other better way to do this?

This code is working for me, but I'm looking in a direction I have mentioned.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my (@space, @freesp);

@space = grep /\/dev\/md0/, `df`;

print "@space\n";

for (@space) {
    chomp;
    @freesp = split /\s+/, $_;
}

if ($freesp[3]/1024/1024 < 2.0) {
    print "Space is less\n";
}
else {
    print "Space is OK\n";
}

#print ($freesp[3]/1024/1024);
```

Comment: [Do not parse `df` output. It's not a good idea.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6351257)

Answer (score 8):

The real solution is [not to use the `-h` option to `df`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/df) if you intend to parse the output with a script.  That way, the output won't contain the "human-readable" `K` / `M` / `G` suffixes in the first place.

You may wish to instead use the `-B1` option, which causes all sizes to be reported in bytes.

---

**Edit:** To answer the literal question, you *could* remove the suffixes and rescale the values appropriately like this:

```
my %units = (K => 2**10, M => 2**20, G => 2**30, T => 2**40,
             P => 2**50, E => 2**60, Z => 2**70, Y => 2**80);

s/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([KMGTPEZY])$/$1 * $units{$2}/e for @freesp[1 .. 3];
```

However, using the `-B1` switch instead of `-h` would give the same result more easily, not to mention more accurately and reliably.

Comment: Ya i know that using the df and dividing with 1024's to get our O/p , but i am wondering if there's any way relative to what i mentioned .........that is if a digit followed by G then replace G/M/K with white space

Comment: **#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my (@space,@freesp);
@space=grep /\/dev\/md0/,`df`;
print "@space\n";

for(@space){
chomp;
@freesp=split /\s+/ ,$_;
}
if ($freesp[3]/1024/1024 < 2.0){
print "Space is less\n";
        }else {
                print "Space is OK\n";
}

#print ($freesp[3]/1024/1024);
** this code is working for me but im looking in a direction i have mentioned ........

Comment: @mViswa What can you possibly hope to gain by using human readable format and deleting `G/M/K` and then comparing? Don't use the `-h` option if you intend to parse the output with a script.

Comment: @mViswa: The reason to not use `-h` and rely on blanking out the letter is because a disk might fill up and report 700M free. 700M is a lot less than 20G, but, when you blank out the letters, 700 > 20.