# Perl: Split up variable from system output (df -lh)

Tags: perl, mount-point

I've managed to use back-ticks to store my `df -lh` command as a variable, `$var`, but I would like to split it up so that each part of the variable can be assigned to another variable.

Here is my output when I print `$var`:

```
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2  931Gi   82Gi  849Gi     9% 21503280 222477462    9%   /
/dev/disk1s2   19Gi  5.0Gi   14Gi    27%  1303373   3579438   27%   /Volumes/Install OS X Yosemite
/dev/disk1s3  1.8Ti  174Gi  1.6Ti    10% 45714072 437656799    9%   /Volumes/store
```

What I would like is to remove the first line of headers, then split it down into the following categories of:

`$filesystem`, `$size`, `$used`, `$avail`, `$cap`, `$mounted`.

I've tried using shift to get rid of the first line, but I am aware now that this is only for arrays. For a different array I have, I use chomp, i.e.

```
foreach my $line (@output) {
              chomp $line;
              my( $filesystem, $size, $used, $avail, $cap, $mounted ) = split (/\s+/, $line);
}
```

But as this is not an array, I don't know how to go about it, unless there is a way to store my system output as an array?

Many thanks.

Comment: "I am aware now that this is only for arrays". But you **can** store the results from backticks in an array.

Comment: The `-h` option for `df` means *human-readable*. Since this is for computer consumption I suggest you use `df -l` instead, to remove all the formatting characters like `K`, `M` and `G` that we real people like

Comment: Good shout, cheers @Borodin, saved me some trouble there, was ending up pulling off the last digits otherwise!

Comment: @DaveCross, have stored in an array now, don't know why I didn't think of that. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/q/6350466/632407 and check https://metacpan.org/pod/Filesys::Df

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `shift` does work on arrays. But backticks in list context will return a list of lines output by the command. You can assign that list to an array and then `shift` the header line off the beginning

Here's an example of what you might write, and the output when I run it on my VBox system. All I do with the fields is print their values as you haven't mentioned what you might want to do with them

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my @df = `df -l`;

shift @df;
chomp @df;

for ( @df ) {
    my ( $filesystem, $size, $used, $avail, $cap, $mounted ) = split ' ', $_, 6;
    say "( $filesystem, $size, $used, $avail, $cap, $mounted )";
}
```

#### output

```
( udev, 1004960, 0, 1004960, 0%, /dev )
( tmpfs, 204852, 6264, 198588, 4%, /run )
( /dev/sda1, 49409840, 4925512, 41951416, 11%, / )
( tmpfs, 1024260, 132, 1024128, 1%, /dev/shm )
( tmpfs, 5120, 4, 5116, 1%, /run/lock )
( tmpfs, 1024260, 0, 1024260, 0%, /sys/fs/cgroup )
( tmpfs, 204852, 52, 204800, 1%, /run/user/1000 )
( /dev/sr0, 56782, 56782, 0, 100%, /media/rob/VBOXADDITIONS_5.0.18_106667 )
```

Comment: I'd suggest you also use the `-P` switch (POSIX-output) to `df`: if filesystem names are long enough, `df` might else split the output into two lines ([shown here](http://askubuntu.com/q/55702/504066)) which makes them harder to parse. `-P` guarantees _"one line of information for each specified file system"_. Note that the output will then _not_ contain the inode columns (as in the OP).

Answer (score 1):

How about using a hash slice approach?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

chomp ( my @header = split ' ', <DATA>, 9 ); 

my @rows; 
while ( <DATA> ) { 
   chomp; 
   my %this_row;
   push @rows, \%this_row;
   @this_row{@header} = split ' ', $_, 9; 
   print Dumper \%this_row;
}

print Dumper \@rows; 


foreach my $row ( @rows ) { 
   print $row -> {Filesystem}, " => ", $row -> {Size},"\n";
}


__DATA__
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2  931Gi   82Gi  849Gi     9% 21503280 222477462    9%   /
/dev/disk1s2   19Gi  5.0Gi   14Gi    27%  1303373   3579438   27%   /Volumes/Install OS X Yosemite
/dev/disk1s3  1.8Ti  174Gi  1.6Ti    10% 45714072 437656799    9%   /Volumes/store
```

We specify a count to split, because it *looks* like it's only your last field that contains spaces. (Otherwise you'd have another column 'on' and that `'Install OS X Yosemite'` would get split too).

This builds a data structure like this:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'Filesystem' => '/dev/disk0s2',
            'Mounted on' => '/',
            'Avail' => '849Gi',
            '%iused' => '9%',
            'Size' => '931Gi',
            'iused' => '21503280',
            'Capacity' => '9%',
            'Used' => '82Gi',
            'ifree' => '222477462'
          },
          {
            'Capacity' => '27%',
            'iused' => '1303373',
            'Size' => '19Gi',
            '%iused' => '27%',
            'Filesystem' => '/dev/disk1s2',
            'Mounted on' => '/Volumes/Install OS X Yosemite',
            'Avail' => '14Gi',
            'ifree' => '3579438',
            'Used' => '5.0Gi'
          },
          {
            'ifree' => '437656799',
            'Used' => '174Gi',
            'Capacity' => '10%',
            'iused' => '45714072',
            '%iused' => '9%',
            'Size' => '1.8Ti',
            'Avail' => '1.6Ti',
            'Mounted on' => '/Volumes/store',
            'Filesystem' => '/dev/disk1s3'
          }
        ];
```

Which is an array of hashes. (e.g. each value is 'keyed').

But you could do something similar where you just `split` the values into an array instead.

Comment: Different way of looking at it! Definitely interested in hashes, will try and incorporate this in another aspect of my code, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My finished code:

```
 my @var= `df -l`;
      my $local_id = 2;
      shift @var; ## REMOVE TOP LINE
      foreach my $line (@var) {
          chomp $line;
          my( $filesystem, $size, $used, $avail, $cap, $mounted ) = split (/\s+/, $line);
          ## DIRTY QUICK WAY TO PULL OFF %
          $cap = substr($cap, 0, -1);
}
```

Df -l does not get rid of the % of capacity, so got rid of that in order to add it into my db. Stored as an array. Thanks everyone for your help and comments!

Comment: Okay, so why did you ask for help with this?

Comment: Didn't realise you could store as an array!

Comment: Unless you're *certain* that the *mounted* field never contains whitespace, you should use `split ' ', $_, 6` as I did