# Perl multiple conditions in IF

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement

This is my code

```
my @usage = `df -hT | grep -e CC -e usr`;
foreach (@usage) {
    if ($_ =~ m/([0-9]{0,3})% \/(.*)/) {
        print "$1 - $2\n";
        if ( ($2 == "CC" && $1 >= 80) || ($2 == "usr" && $1 >= 90) ) {
            print "/$2 parition is at $1% utilization\n";
        }
    }
}
```

It is a simple script to check if a partitions usage.
The problem is in the IF condition.

```
if ( ($2 == "CC" && $1 >= 80) || ($2 == "usr" && $1 >= 90)
```

Should translate to IF (partition is CC and if use is more than 80% ) OR (IF partition is usr and its use is more than 90%) then output.

The my CC partition is at 83% and my usr is at 85%.
Therefore I should only see

**/CC partition is at 83%**

But I get

```
83 - usr
/usr parition is at 85% utilization
83 - CC
/CC parition is at 83% utilization
```

Comment: `use warnings;` would be helpful.

Comment: [Don't parse `df` output.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6350466#comment7437792_6351257) It's not generally machine-readable. Use a module wrapping the statvfs system call instead, e.g. [Filesys::DfPortable](http://p3rl.org/Filesys::DfPortable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `eq` for comparing strings

```
if ( ($2 eq "CC" && $1 >= 80) || ($2 eq "usr" && $1 >= 90) ) {
```